# Data is not being passed with redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Bellow is a code of redirect to route. I am trying to get success variable in view using $success but it is giving error "Undefined variable: success". I also tried passing data in array format to with method. How can I correct it?

```
if ($data->save())

      return redirect('/cases/ppost/notification')->with('success', 'Your case has been posted.')->with('caseNo', $data->id);
```

Comment: Try either `session('success')` or `Session::get('success')`. Both options should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the `redirect()->with()` method does not assign any data to your view, but flashes it to the session:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects

> Returning A Redirect With Flash Data
>
> Redirecting to a new URL and flashing data to the session are
>   typically done at the same time. So, for convenience, you may create a
>   RedirectResponse instance and flash data to the session in a single
>   method chain:
>
> return redirect('user/login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');

This means you will have to access it as such in your view. That would probabaly look something like this:

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't that be ??

```
Redirect::route('/cases/ppost/notification')->with( array('success'=>'Your case has been posted.','caseNo'=>$data->id)) ;
```

Comment: return redirect('user/login')->with('message', 'Login Failed'); 
I have seen it on laravel documentation. 
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses

Comment: then passing an array should work..pass the array please and let me know what do you get..

Comment: you need to use Redirect::route...check here.. array is working..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460068/redirect-route-with-two-parameters-in-with-laravel

Comment: Problem solved.. Only flashing data passes through with function. I fixed it using session('success')..  Thank you for helping me..

Comment: yes, I was right.,..redirect only keeps FLASH related stuff..It doesnt carry the array.. you can pass array as well in larvel.. you will have to use Redirect::route..I hve modified the answer you can use that as well..